# Meaning of 'very detail' in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can someone explain the meaning of 'very detail' in the following sentence?

> The very detail of the questions shows the wide range of issues
> involved.

Does it mean 'exact detail' or 'every detail' or 'small details'? Or did the writer mean to emphasize on something else with the term 'very' here?

Comment: Source of your quote please!

Comment: The writer simply means to emphasize the word ***detail***. Exactly the same "meaning" would apply if the word "detail" were written in *italics* (or in the spoken version, given heavy stress). That's to say - we can tell there are a wide range of issues involved *specifically because of the extreme level of detail*. You might not think too much of the writer's powers of logic and reasoning, but that's what he *means*. Compare *The very size of it was intimidating*.

Comment: Although some left as soon as the speaker had finished, I stayed until the very end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/very), when used before a noun, **very** means

> (used to add emphasis to a noun) exact or particular

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20very%20detail%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20very%20detail%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20very%20detail%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows that the expression "the very detail of" is not common, but it has been in use for a long time, and is still used. here is a typical example:

> Yet the very detail of his picture, detail that in Madame Bovary and Sentimental Education can be revelatory of the essential, often seems to stand in the way of any overall understanding. - *Flaubert in the ruins of Paris (Peter Brook)*

In your sentence, I would suggest **particular** as the most appropriate translation.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+very+detail+of%2C+the+particular+detail+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20very%20detail%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20particular%20detail%20of%3B%2Cc0 No offense meant, but according to this Ngram, _particular_ doesn't have much usage these days either. So I guess either would work.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Maybe **particular** is not used a lot in this kind of sentence, but a) it is used a lot in modern English b) it is mainly used as an adjective, unlike **very** and c) it has a specific, well-understood meaning- a meaning that is appropriate in this context.